# How to convert a binary "string" to a string

Tags: c++

I've been researching this problem for a while now, with nothing coming up. So how would I be able to convert a binary string, to something that I can edit like a string.

Something like this (sorry about the pseudo code.)

```
unsigned char binary = 0100001100001111;

string binaryString = binary.tostring;
//binaryString = 0100001100001111 (as a string)
```

If this is also possible, I was wondering if it was possible to "remove" certain characters off of a string, and replace them with something else. (Kinda like .remove() in C#.)

EDIT: The binary code is stored in

```
unsigned char gfx[32 * 64];
```

And is set in this code:

```
x = V[(opcode & 0x0F00) >> 8];
y = V[(opcode & 0x00F0) >> 4];
height = opcode & 0x000F;

V[0xF] = 0;
for (int yline = 0; yline < height; yline++)
{
    pixel = memory[I + yline];
    for (int xline = 0; xline < 8; xline++)
    {
        if ((pixel & (0x80 >> xline)) != 0)
        {
            if (gfx[(x + xline + ((y + yline) * 64))] == 1)
            {
                V[0xF] = 1;
            }
            gfx[x + xline + ((y + yline) * 64)] ^= 0x1;
        }
    }
}
```

Where `opcode`, `V` and `Pixel` are all hexadecimal values.

Comment: A simple way could be to use a bitset which has a tostring function.

Comment: I'm not quite sure if what you're trying to do makes sense. But couldn't you just use the old *sprintf* function to format your output as a string?

Comment: 0100001100001111 is an octal constant.

Comment: @itsols I hate to ask you, but how exactly would I go about doing that? I came from C#, and I'm still kinda a new to C++.

Comment: Does it contain 0 or 1 per char or each char is a full byte number?

Comment: You are changing your question, and then adding unrelated questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I can see after your edit is that you have an array of chars. So just convert it to a string with the following and then you can use whatever std support you want to process the string. About the rest of your code I am not sure what the goal is.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream> 
#include <algorithm> 
int main() {

    // This does what you asked
    char binary[] = {1,0,1};
    std::string strbinary;    
    for (int i=0; i < sizeof(binary); i++) {
        strbinary.append(std::to_string(binary[i]));
    }
    std::cout << strbinary;     

    //This replace
    std::replace( strbinary.begin(), strbinary.end(), '0', 'y');
    std::cout << strbinary;
}
```

Comment: Your code is a bit hard to understand but if I understood correctly you have an array of char which represent a binary sequence. You can easily convert it into string and then do whatever you need with that.

Comment: @xbirkettx Thank you so much! That fixed it right up.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct bit_string
{
    char data[sizeof(T) * 8 + 1];

    explicit bit_string(T x)
    {
        constexpr size_t n = sizeof(T) * 8;
        for (size_t i = 0; i != n; ++i)
            data[n - i - 1] = (x & (1 << i)) ? '1' : '0';
        data[n] = '\0';
    }

    operator const char * () const
    {
        return data;
    }
};

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    cout << bit_string<unsigned short>(1000) << endl;
}
```

> 0000001111101000